# Gradient of a matrix function with respect to a matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, regression, gradient-descent

I’m trying to compute the gradient of the matrix function $g(W) = \|\vec{y}-\sigma(W\vec{x})\|_2^2$ with respect to $W$ where $\sigma = \sin(x)$ is applied elementwise to the vector. So far I have

$$
(\nabla g)_{ij} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial w_{ij}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{ij}} \left[\sum_{k=1}^N (y_k - \sigma(W\vec{x})_k)^2\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{ij}} \left[\sum_{k=1}^N \left(y_k - \sin\left(\sum_{l=1}^M w_{kl}x_l \right)\right)^2\right]
$$

I’m not sure what to do next, and I’m sure that there’s a much easier way to do it without any expansions but I’m not sure how to take derivatives with respect to $w_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$For typing convenience, define the vector variables
$$\eqalign{
v &= Wx &\qiq dv = dW\,x \\
c &= \cos(v) &\qiq C = \Diag c \\
s &= \sin(v) &\qiq ds =  c\odot dv = \c{C\,dv} \\
p &= s-y &\qiq dp = ds = \c{C\,dW\,x} \\
}$$
and use them to write the cost function and calculate its
differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
g &= p:p \\
dg &= dp:p + p:dp \\
 &= 2p:\c{dp} \\
 &= 2p:\CLR{C\,dW\,x} \\
 &= 2\LR{Cpx^T}:dW \\
\grad{g}{W} &= 2\,Cpx^T \\
}$$
where $(\,:/\,\odot)$ denote the Frobenius/Hadamard products, respectively.

Comment: The norm in the problem is a Euclidean vector norm not a Frobenius norm, wouldn't that make a difference?

Comment: @np-hard For a vector, the Euclidean norm and the Frobenius norm are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the linearity of differentiation and the chain rule:

$$
(\nabla g)_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^N\left[2\left(y_k-\sin\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{kl}x_l\right)\right)\left(-\cos\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{kl}x_l\right)\right)\sum_{l=1}^M\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{ij}}w_{kl}x_l\right]\\
=\sum_{k=1}^N\left[2\left(y_k-\sin\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{kl}x_l\right)\right)\left(-\cos\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{kl}x_l\right)\right)\sum_{l=1}^M\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}x_l\right]\\
=-2\left[y_i-\sin\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{il}x_l\right)\right]\cos\left(\sum_{l=1}^Mw_{il}x_l\right)x_j
$$

Notice that you have a part depending only on $i$ and another depending only on $j$ so you might want to condense it into

$$
\nabla g=\nabla D\vert_{Wx}\cdot x^T
$$

with $D(z):=\lVert y-\sin(z)\rVert_2^2$.